# How indexing improved database query?

Tags: database, indexing, system-design

I get the idea of how indexing works to improve the speed of database query. But isn't it just a datastructure outside of our main table, which have pointers to our rows in the main table. We can then sort the indexing and execute Binary Search on it to get the id (for example) of a row the we need but aren't we also need to turn to the main table and execute find by id in that table, if that's the case then isn't the query also requires O(N), or I understand indexing wrong?

Comment: Both index search and primary key (ID, is indexed internally also) search are O(log N) operations - search for b-tree.

Comment: @Arvo you mean the findById operation is also O(logN)?, but what if the primary key in the table isn't sorted?

Comment: Primary key is indexed always; records may not be sorted on it, but primary key index refers to correct record directly.

Comment: @Arvo ohh so if we can get the primary key of the row, we can directly jump to that record and get the data right away, not like the database do linear search to find the record with correct primary key. Thank you so much